# How to access java library classes in Freemarker template

Tags: java, freemarker, template-engine, smooks

I am using smooks library for XML to XML transformation. Following is the smooks configuration. In freemarker template I want to access jdk library classes and also the classes that I have created in the project. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
                  xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.3.xsd"
                  xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd">

    <core:filterSettings type="SAX" defaultSerialization="false" />
    <resource-config selector="Order">
        <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
    </resource-config>

    <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="Order">
        <ftl:template>
    <!--
        <#assign x="${Order.OrderLines.OrderLine[0].@FulfillmentType}">
        <order requestNumber="${Order.@OrderNo}"
           customerEmail="${Order.@CustomerEMailID}"
           orderNumber="${Order.@CustomerPONo}"
           dateTimePlaced="${Order.@OrderDate}"
           shipNodeID="${Order.@ShipNode}"
           <#if x == "S2H" >
           deliveryType="SHIPTOHOME"
           </#if>
           >
        </order>-->
        </ftl:template>
    </ftl:freemarker>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to Java objects and classes (for static utilities) is supposed to be provided through the data-model (template context) by the caller. I suppose Smooks won't do it though. But if you are allowed to configure FreeMarker under Smooks, then you can add so called "shared variables" to the FreeMarker configuration, which will be available for all templates, without adding them to the data-model (see `freemarker.template.Configuration.setSharedVariable()`). As a last resort, you can use something like `'com.example.MyObjectProvider'?new()` to smuggle your Java objects in, where `MyObjectProvider` implements `TemplateMethodModelEx` (or any other `TemplateModel` interface).